# Printing Extended-Ascii Characters In Python 3 In Both Windows and Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

I've found quite a few questions that appear identical to this - but despite my best efforts I'm not able to get any of the solutions to work.

I'm trying to print extended-ascii characters to make an old text-based menu.  Here is my original code:

```
print('╔════════════════════════════════════╗')
print('║           Hello World!             ║')
print('╚════════════════════════════════════╝')
```

When I run the .py file my output looks like this:

```
??????????????????????????????????????
?           Hello World!             ?
??????????????????????????????????????
```

I am using Python 3.3.1 and need a solution that will 'just work' in both Windows and Linux.  I've tried using `chcp 65001` in my Windows Console, without any luck.

I've tried using 'setdefaultencoding' but I believe it no longer applies to Python 3.

Comment: How are the characters encoded in the source code? Latin-1? UTF-8?

Comment: This appears to be a problem with Python and how it handles character encoding.  I find the code works and does not work depending on what platform you are on.  When on the web it is the hardest.  I don't think there is a current solution for Python 3.6 (current at the time this message was written).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be a better way, but how about something like this:

```
dic = {
'\\' : b'\xe2\x95\x9a',
'-'  : b'\xe2\x95\x90',
'/'  : b'\xe2\x95\x9d',
'|'  : b'\xe2\x95\x91',
'+'  : b'\xe2\x95\x94',
'%'  : b'\xe2\x95\x97',
}

def decode(x):
    return (''.join(dic.get(i, i.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8') for i in x))

print(decode('+------------------------------------%'))
print(decode('|           Hello World!             |'))
print(decode('\\------------------------------------/'))
```

Windows:

```
C:\Temp>python temp.py
╔════════════════════════════════════╗
║           Hello World!             ║
╚════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Linux:

```
$ python3 temp.py 
╔════════════════════════════════════╗
║           Hello World!             ║
╚════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: @RobP. Please note that it will translate hyphens in normal sentences too, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

With Python 3 and its Unicode strings, your original code should work just fine as long as you follow these rules:

- Save your file in an encoding that supports the characters.
- Declare source encoding via `#coding: <encoding>` if it is not the UTF-8 default.
- The default console encoding supports the characters.
- The console font supports the character glyphs.

Note the `coding` statement I added below is *optional* because `utf8` is the default on Python 3.  Just make sure your file is actually saved in the correct encoding.

```
# coding: utf8
print('╔════════════════════════════════════╗')
print('║           Hello World!             ║')
print('╚════════════════════════════════════╝')
```

Output on my Windows console (code page 437, Consolas font):

```
╔════════════════════════════════════╗
║           Hello World!             ║
╚════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Output on my PythonWin IDE (UTF-8 encoding, and the usual Linux default, plus Courier New font):

```
╔════════════════════════════════════╗
║           Hello World!             ║
╚════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Note `chcp 65001` (UTF-8) is buggy on Windows and/or Python 3:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════╗
��═══════════════════════╗
�══════════════╗
�════════╗
�════╗
��═╗
��
║           Hello World!             ║
��
╚════════════════════════════════════╝
��═══════════════════════╝
�══════════════╝
�════════╝
�════╝
��═╝
��
```

Also note `setdefaultdecoding` was never required, even on Python 2.  Unicode strings just weren't the default.  This code works on Python 2.X *and* Python 3.3 and later, as Python 3.3 added the optional `u''` syntax back to aid in porting Python 2.X code:

```
# coding: utf8
print(u'╔════════════════════════════════════╗')
print(u'║           Hello World!             ║')
print(u'╚════════════════════════════════════╝')
```

Comment: I've been annoyed by the `chcp 65001` issue for a long time. See http://bugs.python.org/issue14227 and http://bugs.python.org/issue1602.

Comment: I see. The problem is that native English speakers meet the situation only in cases like that :) (I mean Windows developers and Python developers).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I can observe. Notice that the default encoding was 852 in my case (Windows 7, Czech). The code was stored in UTF-8, and Python 3.3.0 was used.

[image]

It seems to be bug, but I do not know whether in Python, in Windows console, or between my chair or keyboard.